# mysql_real_escape_string For doctrine (symfony)?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, escaping

Is there `mysql_real_escape_string` for doctrine?

Because I have a query like

```
?´## '´` ^#11 " dfvü:?=._`ßß?(%%/ '
```

and i must escape it, before i give it to `Doctrine_Query::create()`

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine handles escaping internally. Use a query like:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('MyTable m')->where('m.column = ?', '?´## \'´^#11 " dfvü:?=._ßß?(%%/');
```

And the characters will be escaped to be safe for your database.

Answer (score -1):

It cannot work, because

```
where('m.column = ?', '?´## '´^#11 " dfvü:?=._ßß?(%%/');
```

Here are three apostrophes

```
'?´## '´^#11 " dfvü:?=._ßß?(%%/'
```